# Is this a secure way to handle cookies?

Tags: security, cookies, web

The scenario is a web app running with no ability to store information locally, such as sessions. So in order to provide state, here's what I'm thinking. The server has a list of users and `SHA256(passwords + salt)`. When a user logs in, I would set a name cookie with the username and a key cookie with `SHA256(SHA256(password + salt) . ip)`.

This would allow the server to compare the credentials without knowing the plain text password, it wouldn't expose the password in the client's cookie, and would safeguard the logged in credentials against being ex-filtrated into an attacker's system since it would only work on that one IP address.

The only drawback I can see is that there would be no way to enforce expiry. So it would basically be a lifetime cookie for that user/password/IP combination, or at least until the web app erases the cookie or the user changes his password.

Comment: I think you should introduce the concept of sessions as the can be expired easily either manually or on date/time. Also, the cookie should be based on a secure randomly generated value rather than a hash of the password value.

Comment: I don't see any other problem more than what you pointed. But if you have a list of users and password, why you can't add an unique token list related to the users list and then just write the token into the cookie (basically sessions)?

Answer (score 1):

you must not use password anywhere in cookie even if it is encrypted.
give every user an id and on every login you must:
1. Update login Time
2. Create unique session Id
3. set cookie with unique session id

now on every request to server
1. validate session cookie
2. Check login time and current server time.

it is just basic structure..

Comment: You realize hashes are one-way functions? No one is reversing sha256 any time soon. Plus the whole point of this question is a situation where no session information can be saved, hence your solution doesn't work.

Comment: May be what you want cannot be achieved.. because you must save something to identify user.. and i personally think it is variable unique session id for every user.. How you create good session id is upon you.. whick encryption techniques you use..

Comment: As Dendory mentioned, your answer doesn't make sense. 1- encrypted != hashed ... 2- You didn't address his question, please say why it's not a safe way instead of just suggesting him to do what he said he couldn't do.

Comment: you said it cannot store information locally. and ironically you are storing a cookie with hashed credentials. If you could store cookie.. then set its expiry time say 1hour or whatever. or as @silverlightfox said introduce sessions..